# SQL comparing two select clauses and grouping sums

Tags: python, html, sql

I am currently working on a project at the university and I'm having trouble with a specific query in SQL.
[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RABNA.png)

I am trying to retrieve a list of the NOM from DEPARTEMENTS where there is more WOMEN that graduated than MEN using the ANNEE(year) and LABEL(level) that we have to input ourselves through HTML forms.

so far I have this:

```
select distinct NOM from 
    DEPARTEMENTS as d1, 
    NB_DIPLOMES_DEPT as d2, 
    NIVEAUX_DIPLOMES as d3 
  where d1.NUM=d2.DEPT and d2.NIVEAU=d3.ID 
    and (select sum(num) 
  from NB_DIPLOMES_DEPT 
  where sexe='F') > 
    (select sum(num) from NB_DIPLOMES_DEPT where sexe='H') 
        and ANNEE='{0}' AND LABEL='{1}'".format(year,level)
```

But I don't know how to compare the sum of the number of women and men.

Comment: What's the `NIVEAUX_DIPLOMES` table for? Why do you need it?

Comment: @TheImpaler Because you get the LABEL from it (value that I retrieve with a select tag in html)

Answer (score 0):

When using sub queries, remember to join with the main FROM. Otherwise you'll get unexpected results.

```
select NOM 
from DEPARTEMENTS as dep 
where (
    select sum(num)
    from NB_DIPLOMES_DEPT ndd
        , NIVEAUX_DIPLOMES nd
    where ndd.sexe='F'
        and ndd.DEPT = dep.NUM
        and ndd.ANNE = ?
        and ndd.NIVEAU = nd.ID
        and nd.LABEL = ?
) > (
    select sum(num) 
    from NB_DIPLOMES_DEPT 
    where sexe='H'
        and ndd.DEPT = dep.NUM
        and ndd.ANNE = ?
        and ndd.NIVEAU = nd.ID
        and nd.LABEL = ?
)
```

In your SQL, you where joining only

```
DEPARTEMENTS as d1, 
NB_DIPLOMES_DEPT as d2, 
NIVEAUX_DIPLOMES as d3
```

The sub queries always returned all the values